# How to force route() helper to return HTTPS while not breaking SignedURL while behind proxy?

Tags: laravel, proxy

My app is behind proxy which offload the SSL. The request reaching my app will always be HTTP. Using TrustedProxies config solves this. However, this trigger mixed content warning which is blocking my ajax call. For asset, i already use secure_asset() helper.

I have configured wildcard IPs in TrustedProxies config. I also used secure_asset() helper.

I want to force route() helper to return HTTPS while not breaking SignedURL while behind proxy.

Comment: Try using `URL::forceScheme('https');`. This should create your links with `https` instead of `http`

Comment: @adam If i don't force the scheme, signed url works as intended. But this will failed my ajax call, since route helper return http and browser will block mixed-content. I'm stuck in the middle